# Xcode Cannot find type 'HomeView' in scope

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview

Xcode could't find custom UIView class. And if I try to make a simple class like a model it will work normally, but Xcode aslo can't completion code.

This is ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var hView: HomeView!
    var testModel: TestModel!

    private func initView(){
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        initView()
    }

}
```

And this is custom class:

````
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class AboutView: UIView{
    
    var rootOfTop: UIImageView!
    var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    var messaageButton: UIButton!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        installRootOfTop()
        installSearchBar()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    // MARK: - Install widget.
    private func installRootOfTop(){
        rootOfTop = UIImageView()
            // ...
        self.addSubview(rootOfTop)
        
        rootOfTop.snp.makeConstraints{ 
            // ...
        }
    }
    
    private func installSearchBar(){
        searchBar = UISearchBar()
            // ...
        self.rootOfTop.addSubview(searchBar)
        
        searchBar.snp.makeConstraints{ 
            //...
        }
    }
    
} ```[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfxZK.jpg

By the way, if I create a new project it also work abnormal, but previous project work normally.
I suspect it's because Xcode temp, but i can't find the project's temp, also i think it's third base, but the new project work abnormal as the same.
````

Comment: Go to the Interface Builder and select a UIView object in question and change its class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that the content of your `HomeView.swift` file?
If true, your class name is wrong.

The file name and the class name don't match for `HomeView.swift`.
You are declaring an `AboutView` class inside it, that's why Xcode can't find it.

Comment: Thanks for u ! That's my error, i have not notice this file's name and class's name